# TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'ConvTokenizer' (type ConvTokenizer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, data-science

```
# Compile
opt = AdamW(learning_rate=Learning_Rate, weight_decay=Weight_Decay)
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=[
        Accuracy(name="Top1Accuracy"), TopKAccuracy(k=3, name="Top3Accuracy")
    ]
)

history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=test_ds, 
    epochs=5
)
```

Errors

### Epoch 1/5

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-7205730bf123> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(
2     train_ds,
3     validation_data=test_ds,
4     epochs=5
5 )

2 frames
/tmp/*autograph_generated_filek8fd0koq.py in tf__call(self, X)
9                 retval* = ag_.UndefinedReturnValue()
10                 patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).net, (ag__.ld(X),), None, fscope)
---> 11                 patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reshape, (ag__.ld(patches),), dict(shape=(-1, ag__.ld(patches).shape[1] * ag__.ld(patches).shape[2], ag__.ld(patches).shape[-1])), fscope)
12                 try:
13                     do_return = True

TypeError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filek8fd0koq.py", line 11, in tf__call
    patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reshape, (ag__.ld(patches),), dict(shape=(-1, ag__.ld(patches).shape[1] * ag__.ld(patches).shape[2], ag__.ld(patches).shape[-1])), fscope)

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'ConvTokenizer' (type ConvTokenizer).

in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-15-42735b3fa65d>", line 19, in call  *
        patches = tf.reshape(patches, shape=(-1, patches.shape[1]*patches.shape[2], patches.shape[-1]))

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'


Call arguments received by layer 'ConvTokenizer' (type ConvTokenizer):
  • X=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, None), dtype=float32)
```